# Two persons simultaneously using one MacBook Pro (working in two apps simultaneous )

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

Is it possible for such a setup as the following: Hooking one MacBook Pro up with two separate monitors, allowing two different persons to work independently on their monitors, sharing the computer's performance?

Perhaps this is a strange request, but it would actually be useful for me in certain situations. (I will be working in one monitor and in the another one my daughter will be playing.) I ask cause I do not know how focus will work in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two people using the same graphical user session, with different input devices, is not possible on macOS.

### Remote Session - VNC

However, you can [remote log into a Mac](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/vnc) and share the computer's performance. Remote log in will give you two graphical user sessions running on one Mac.

You could use an inexpensive computer, such as a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org), and have it remotely connect to your MacBook Pro. One user could then use the Mac directly and the other via the remote connection and a monitor.